# Can i rewrite these statements in a better way?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can i rewrite these statements in a better way, using one update statement with a case in it or something or i just leave them like this and wrap in a transaction?

```
 DECLARE @currentFailedPassCount int = 
       ( SELECT FailedPasswordAttemptCount FROM Users WHERE Username=@username );
 UPDATE Users 
      SET FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount=FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount+1 
      WHERE Username=@username;
 IF(@currentFailedPassCount=5) 
      UPDATE Users 
      SET IsLockedOut=1 
      WHERE Username=@username;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount=FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount+1,
    IsLockedOut = CASE
                     WHEN FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount >= 4 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                  END
WHERE Username=@username;
```

I don't think it reads as nicely (personal preference) but it's a single statement.

Comment: You can use `FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount += 1` in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @currentFailedPassCount int = ( SELECT FailedPasswordAttemptCount FROM Users      WHERE Username=@username );

IF(@currentFailedPassCount=4)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users
    SET FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount=5, IsLockedOut=1
    WHERE Username=@username;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users
    SET FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount=FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount+1
    WHERE Username=@username;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Users 
SET 
    FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount=FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount + 1, 
    IsLockedOut=case 
        when FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 4 then 1 
        else IsLockedOut 
    end
WHERE Username=@username
```